# Trying to use text classification and receiving error code

Tags: python, tfidfvectorizer

Code inputted:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)
X_train_counts.shape

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf.shape
```

Error message:

```
NameError: name 'tfidf_transformer' is not defined
```

I am very new to this so please bear with me.

Why am I getting this error message? I have defined `tfidf_transformer` haven't I?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: I second @JacobIRR,  I cannot reproduce this problem either.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

use :
TfidfTransformer().fit(X_train_counts) instead of  tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).